# Integral on triangle Bivariate

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I can't see why the integral
$$
J=P(Z_1>0,Z_2>0,Z_1+Z_2<1)
$$
can be computed as
$$
J = \left(F(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \qquad (*)
$$
where $F$ is the cumulative probability distribution (gaussian)
and $Z_1,Z_2$ are independent standard normal random variables.

---

What I observe : the events are not independent. $Z_1+Z_2 \sim N(0,2)$ but I can't see why $(*)$ is true.

Here is the source : Suess et al., Introduction to Probability Simulation and Gibbs Sampling with R, 2010 (page 69)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can argue as follow by symmetry, using the transformation $(Z_1,Z_2)\to (Z_1+Z_2,Z_1-Z_2)$ (which preserves independence) :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[-1<Z_1+Z_2 < 1,-1 < Z_1-Z_2 < 1] &= \mathbb P[Z_1> 0,Z_2> 0, Z_1+Z_2 <1]\\&+\mathbb P[Z_1\leq 0,Z_2> 0, Z_1-Z_2 >-1]\\&+\mathbb P[Z_1> 0,Z_2\leq 0, Z_1-Z_2 <1]\\&+\mathbb P[Z_1\leq 0,Z_2\leq 0, Z_1+Z_2 >-1]\\
&=4\cdot \mathbb P[Z_1> 0,Z_2> 0, Z_1+Z_2 <1]\\
\end{align*}
But since $Z_1+Z_2$ and $Z_1-Z_2$ are independent we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[Z_1> 0,Z_2> 0, Z_1+Z_2 <1] &= \frac{1}{4}\cdot \mathbb P[-1<Z_1+Z_2 < 1,-1 < Z_1-Z_2 < 1]\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \cdot \mathbb P[-1<Z_1+Z_2 < 1]\mathbb P[-1 < Z_1-Z_2 < 1]\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left( F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)-F\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) \right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left( F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)-1+F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) \right)^2\\
&=\left( F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \right)^2
\end{align*}